# Pharika's Mender, Gray Merchant of Asphodel, Rescue From The Underworld

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an [Elvish Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Mystic) (*EM*) and [Pharika Mender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pharika%20Mender) (*PM*) in my graveyard, and a [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant%20of%20Asphodel) (*GMOA*)on the battlefield. At the end of my opponent's turn, I play [Rescue from The Underworld](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rescue%20from%20The%20Underworld) (*RFTU*), sacrificing my *GMOA* as the additional cost to cast it. I choose *PM* as my target for *RFTU*.

During my upkeep, *GMOA* and *PM* enters the battlefield and their trigger are put on the stack. I place *PM's* trigger first, and then *GMOA's* trigger.

In respond to *GMOA's* trigger, my opponent kills *GMOA*, and then *GMOA's* trigger resolves -- which means *PM's* trigger resolves next.

When *PM's* trigger resolves, am I able to target *GMOA* to return it to my hand?

Comment: Can we use the proper abbreviation for "Gray Merchant of Asphodel", *Gary*? =)

Comment: Also, why wouldn't you put *GMOA*'s trigger on first, and then *PM*'s trigger? This way, you could bring back a Black permanent for a higher devotion count for *GMOA*'s trigger.

Comment: Pharika's trigger returns the card to your hand, so devotion count doesn't change, as much as I'd like it to. ; )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**

The targets of abilities and spells are chosen *as these go on the stack*, so you should have had a target chosen already even before the merchant died in the first place.